# What is the difference between supersymmetry and MSSM?

Tags: terminology, supersymmetry, beyond-the-standard-model, mssm

What is the difference between [supersymmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetry) and [MSSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Supersymmetric_Standard_Model)? Please explain in a simple language i am just a beginner of supersymmetry

Answer (score 0):

Supersymmetry is a symmetry, in particular one which makes properties of particles of different spin to be related, e.g. fermions and scalars are related.

MSSM is a model, it has a concrete Lagrangian and specific matter field, gauge interactions, etc. It is by design what you get once you accept all the fermions of the Standard Model, all its gauge interactions, all its Yukawa interactions to respect the symmetry between fermions and bosons, up to small effects that cease to be important at high energy.